# Geosearch Esri controls in leaflet

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, leaflet, google-maps, openlayers-2

It is possible to disable the Geosearch Esri controls in leaflet after the first geocode search? When I run Chrome console and I select the search geocode icon this is the code:

```html
<input class="geocoder-control-input leaflet-bar">
```

I have tried to disable it using

```js
$('.geocoder-control-input leaflet-bar').attr('disabled', true);
```

but it doesn't work.

Comment: By "disabled" you mean just like "grayed out" so you cannot click on the button, or is removing the search button from the map an acceptable solution?

Comment: The first option so when you click on search button nothing happens.

Comment: Can u give a screen Capture !

Answer (score 2):

i think the fact that we currently define an [anonymous function](https://github.com/Esri/esri-leaflet-geocoder/blob/master/src/Controls/Geosearch.js#L285-L288) to dicate what happens when users click on the control is why [`L.domEvent.removeListener`](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#domevent-removelistener) can't be used to 'disable' it later programmatically from within a client app (more info [here](https://groups.google.com/g/leaflet-js/c/zkSPjuS_Uc4)).

it sounded like a pretty good idea to me, so i went ahead and submitted a [pull request](https://github.com/Esri/esri-leaflet-geocoder/pull/121) to add wrappers to esri leaflet geocoder to conveniently `disable()` and `enable()` the control in our next release.

ps: there's no need to tag your questions with unrelated APIs (like Open Layers and Google maps)

Comment: now that's what I call service

Comment: next time i'm just going to stub out an issue and assign you @Stephen Lead ;)